# Finding a Transformation for a Sum of Exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, exponential-function, transformation

I am looking to see if it is possible to find a transformation $T_i(f(x))$ such that

$$T_1\left(e^x+e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=e^x-ie^{ix}-e^{-x}+ie^{-ix}$$
$$T_2\left(e^x+e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=e^x-e^{ix}+e^{-x}-e^{-ix}$$
$$T_3\left(e^x+e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=e^x+ie^{ix}-e^{-x}-ie^{-ix}$$

It might be easier to write also in terms of powers of $i$ here, instead.  Thus

$$T_1\left(e^x+e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=i^4e^x+i^3e^{ix}+i^2e^{-x}+i^1e^{-ix}$$
$$T_2\left(e^x+e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=i^4e^x+i^2e^{ix}+e^{-x}+i^{2}e^{-ix}$$
$$T_3\left(e^x+i^1e^{ix}+e^{-x}+e^{-ix}\right)=e^x+ie^{ix}+i^2e^{-x}+i^3e^{-ix}$$

I have not studied transformations in a while and I don't know of what kind of mechanism could leave the exponential power in tact but simply alter the complex coefficent power.  I have tried using substitution methods but nothing is getting me very far. For example, a simple substitution such as $x=-iy$ will simply permute the summands.  But since the coefficient powers are also changing, you can't simply use a complex scalar here either.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the conditions in terms of trigonometric and hyperbolic sines and cosines?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales : you mean in term of $\cos^{-1}$ and $\cosh^{-1}$

Comment: I haven't, mainly because I'm also interested in other roots of unity as well.  For example instead of using a 4 summand expression, what if I used $w_5$ instead of $i=w_4$...

Comment: No, $2\cosh x=e^x+e^{-x}$, $2\sinh x=e^x-e^{-x}$,$2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$,$2\sin x=ie^{-ix}-ie^{ix}$.

Comment: ..........I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but with
$$
 T_1(f) = f''', \quad T_2(f) = f'', \quad T_3(f) = f'
$$
your given equations are satisfied.